# DataGridView issues

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to loop through my foreach loops and spit out output to my datagridview.

The datagridview has 3 defined columns:  Path, Old File Name, New File Name

However, I keep hitting errors.

First, here is the code:

```
public partial class SanitizeFileNames : Form
{

    public SanitizeFileNames()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Sanitizer(List<string> paths)
    {
    string regPattern = (@"[~#&!%+{}]+");
        string replacement = "";

        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);
        List<string> existingNames = new List<string>();

        StreamWriter errors = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.smith\Desktop\SharePointTesting\Errors.txt", true);
        StreamWriter resultsofRename = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.smith\Desktop\SharePointTesting\Results of File Rename.txt", true);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        var filesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();


           try
            {

              foreach (string files2 in paths)
              {

                string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(files2);
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
                string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);


                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sanitized))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);
                    DataGridViewRow dgr2 = new DataGridViewRow();
                    dgr2.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    dgr2.Cells[1].Value = filenameOnly;
                    dgr2.Cells[2].Value = sanitized;
                    resultsofRename.Write("Path: " + pathOnly + "\r\n" + "Old File Name: " + filenameOnly + "\r\n" + "New File Name: " + sanitized + "\r\n" + "\r\n");

                }

                else
                {
                    if (filesCount.ContainsKey(sanitized))
                    {
                        filesCount[sanitized]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesCount.Add(sanitized, 1);
                    }
                    string newFileName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sanitized),
                    filesCount[sanitized].ToString(),
                    Path.GetExtension(sanitized));
                    string newFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(sanitized), newFileName);
                    System.IO.File.Move(files2, newFilePath);
                    DataGridViewRow dgr2 = new DataGridViewRow();
                    dgr2.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    dgr2.Cells[1].Value = filenameOnly;
                    dgr2.Cells[2].Value = newFileName;
                    resultsofRename.Write("Path: " + pathOnly + "\r\n" + "Old File Name: " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files2) + "\r\n" + "New File Name: " + newFileName + "\r\n" + "\r\n");
                }
               }
              }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

             errors.Write(e);

            }





    }

    private void SanitizeFileNames_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

First off, I'm new to C# so I'm not even 100% sure this is correct.  What this code does is take paths that are passed in from another method and "clean" the file names by removing invalid chars (as defined in my regex pattern).  If the file name already exists, append the filename with a number that increases incrementally (i.e. ~test.txt and %test.txt would both be renamed to test.txt.  with my code, ~test.txt becomes test.txt and %test.txt becomes test1.txt).
I'm trying basically to append this data to my datagridview (should the file go to the else if(filesCount.ContainsKey(sanitized) loop).

I get errors with Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(), Path.GetExtension(), Path.Combine(), Path.GetDIrectoryName().  The error is as follows:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'GetFileName' and no extension method
>   'GetFileName' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have no idea what this means or how to fix this.  Can someone help?

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting that error based on the code above.  But let me ask you this, is there a reason you need to use a data grid?  Maybe it would be simpler to just use an <asp:Table> if you're going to generate the rows and columns manually and not bind to anything.

If you think that could work, I could provide you some sample code for that.

Comment: from the code you posted I cannot see where the compile error would be. can you indicate the line(s) you are getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn variable/field  called 'Path' somewhere. Rename that variable and/or use the full name `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` etc.

As a more general remark, stop using the DatagridView as a data-structure. Do yourself a favor, define a class with the (column) properties you want, declare a `BindingList<MyFileClass>` and bind the DataGridView to that list.

Comment: I think that's `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()`  Also, ++ to having a column named Path.  That's almost 100% guaranteed what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
public ArrayList GetSelectedRows(DataGrid datagrid)
{
ArrayList arrSelectedRows = new ArrayList();
DataSet dset = (DataSet)datagrid.DataSource;
for (int i=0; i<dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
if (datagrid.IsSelected(i))
{
DataRow drow = dset.Tables[0].Rows[i];
arrSelectedRows.Add(drow);
}
}
return arrSelectedRows;
}
```

This should get you were you want to go...though, obviously not quite like what you were after either.

```
This should get you were you want to go...though, obviously not quite like what you were after either.
```